# Public Key per APP on Android Marketplace, Possible?

Tags: android, google-play, android-lvl

Implimenting the licensing features for the Android Marketplace, and have run into a problem/question.

If I have more than 1 app in testing, how do I have the marketplace licensing return a diffent code to my testers based on App?  IE App 1 I want everyone to get rejected, but app 2 should be getting OKAY... I don't see how to do this.

Must I buy another developer account to accomplish this? And if so, what issues does this bring up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot set a hard coded  licence responses per application in Market as it stands (I don't work for Google so I don't know if they are ever going to change that).

Creating a second developer account won't help either as you will have a package name clash unless you really want to go through all the aggravation of changing the package name each build.

So at the moment there's no easy solution to this.

Comment: Well I was talking about 2 different apps, so they each have an independent package name so no collision there, however there is still only one setting at the developer account leve for your public key response as far as I can find.